# Tinylog 2 - setting an absoute file path for log files

Tags: android, tinylog

Environment:  Android 13
Programing Language: Java
IDE: Android Studio

I wish to set an absolute directory into which Tinylog 2 writes log files.

Two questions:

1. How do I set this up, for example to use directory:  "/storage/emulated/0/MyLogs"?
2. Does Tinylog 2 handle file permissions in Android 13?  If not what must I do so Tinylog 2 can write to any external storage directory?  My apps do not need any file permissions.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: You can find an Android example project using tinylog here: https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-android-example

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
/storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyLogs
```

to be able to create/write files. –

For Android 13+ you do not need to request any permission.

You have write permission in public Documents dir on external storage by default.